# Multicore clock counter consistency

Tags: c, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

I am trying to measure a difference of clock counters between two time points at a kernel module. I use the following function named `get_ccnt()` to get a clock counter value at a certain time:

```
static __inline__ long long int get_ccnt(void)
{
    #if defined(__i386__)
        long long int x;
        __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
        return x;

    #elif defined(__x86_64__)
        unsigned int hi, lo;
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
        return ( (long long int)lo)|( ((long long int)hi)<<32 );

    #endif
}
```

What I concern is, I am using HP EliteBook 2530p in which Intel Core 2 Duo SL9400 ([spec. reference](http://www.pcworld.com/product/43873/elitebook-2530p-notebook.html))

I heard that CPUs after `Nehalem` has a consistent clock counter over all cores. (*If I get wrong, please point it out.*) But, Intel Core 2 Duo SL 9400 has a code name `Penryn`.

Thus, I think if a kernel module moves from one core to another between two time points, then consistency between two cores is compromised and I can't get a right clock difference.

Is it right what I am thinking? If it is, is there a way to fix it (e.g. fix a kernel module not to move a core to a core?)

Comment: I found out [THIS](https://aufather.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/high-performance-time-measuremen-in-linux/) article.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that he/she tries to solve the problem by binding a processor to a certain CPU affinity. I will try and check it later.

Comment: Your app shouldn't be "switching between cores" even if multi-threaded. (Each thread runs independently.) If trying to profile two threads on different cores, you could time each core's usage independently and add both results together for a total time. (Assuming you want to stick with RDTSC.) Or force all threads to be on the same core. Otherwise, doing the RDTSC on the main thread should return the correct elapsed time to return to that thread, regardless of any other threads. It will give jitter in almost every case however, as the kernel/OS allocates and runs them as it sees fit.

Comment: @rdtsc Your name makes your answer trustworthy. Thanks a lot. I will check it I have the time.

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately. This has almost nothing to do with C as the language in which you express your program (and this isn't even C) but a lot with your OS. "kernel" is linux kernel for you?

Comment: It is only an issue when you have multiple processors, physical chips on the motherboard.  It is not an issue with a processor with multiple cores, like your laptop has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the comments linked mentions that setting the process affinity can achieve what you want. I would also suggest making a custom version of `get_ccnt()` whereby replacing **RDTSC** with **RDTSCP**. The latter is a variant of the former which also returns the cpuid with the cycle counter. You could check that your initial measurement's cpuid is equal to the final measurement's cpuid.

Have a look at Section 3.2 of [this Intel manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf). Be sure to make a test first to verify that your processor supports this instruction.